# Using the Python Zipfile's extract in Unix

Tags: python, linux, unix, zip

I'm trying to unzip a zip file named "fname" using this code in a Python script named "unzipper.py" by using the python module "zipfile":
    `

```
fh = open(fname, 'rb')
z = zipfile.ZipFile(fh)
for name in z.namelist():
    print("Extracting " + name)
    dirNameFile = dStr + "_" + name.split('.')[0]
    path = dirNameZip + "/" + dirNameFile + "/content"
    if os.path.isfile(path + name):
        os.remove(path + name)
    z.extract(name, path)
    if not os.path.isdir(path + "/streams"):
        os.mkdir(path + "/streams")
fh.close()
`
```

This works fine in Windows but in Linux the output is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unzipper.py", line 31, in ?
    z.extract(name, path)
AttributeError: ZipFile instance has no attribute 'extract'
```

The 'zipfile' python module is supposed to be cross-platform, so why is there still a difference?
Thanks alot

Comment: My guess is that Linux system is using a very old version of Python; [ZipFile.extract](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extract) was added in Python 2.6

Comment: Indeed it was... 2.4 ! =S
Alternative solution...?

Comment: Upgrade it. There is no reason for anything on this planet to try to run Python 2.4, especially for new code.

Comment: If you need to accommodate that old system and you can't upgrade it  then you have to use `ZipFile.read()` to get the bytes from the archive and then save those bytes to the desired destination using the standard file `open` and `write` methods.